# Easiest Way to Combine Two Statements for UIButton

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I'm trying to condense my code, and I know there's an easier way than writing out two separate lines, but I can't seem to get the syntax just right. What I'm essentially doing is assigning **an image** to my `UIButton`, passing it to a method to automatically resize it, and then setting the title to `NULL`. Any ideas?

My code :

```
[self.btnA setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[self resizeImageWithImage:[UIImage 
  imageNamed:@"A_3rdStroke.png"] toSize:CGSizeMake(100, 100)]]];
[self.btnA setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: 1) What you are doing is the correct way. 2) Why do you think combining those two lines into one is a better way?

Comment: Why are you setting the image as a color? Buttons can have images.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to set the image of a button while also calling my Resize method; the color was the only way I could make it work. 
@Rmaddy: I'm still new to Obj-C so always wondering if I'm making things too complicated.

Comment: Michelle - You're setting two separate properties.  Two lines is fine, normal, and expected.  Is there a title showing that you're trying to make 'nil'? If not, you can omit that line.  Can you show the code for setting the image that wasn't working?  Of course it's debatable, but in my opinion, if it doesn't affect performance, readability is preferable to succinctness.

Answer (score 0):

maybe:

```
- (void)setButton:(UIButton *)button withImageName:(NSString *)imageName {
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[self resizeImageWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] toSize:CGSizeMake(100, 100)]]];
    [button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

and you can call it from your class like this:

```
[self setButton:self.btnA withImageName:@"A_3rdStroke.png"];
```

---

optionally, you could put such method into a *category* for the `UIButton` class (which needs to include your `-resizeImageWithImage:toSize:` method as well).